# How to send post req and save data with foreign key in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, relational-database

Note, UserInfo and their relationship is every user can have many notes and only one related user info.

i tried to map entities but when i send a post request to save a note belongs to a user, the user_id column is always null.

Here is my classes and the request i sent:

Note model:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "notes")
public class Note {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "checklist_name", nullable = false)
    private String checklistName;

    @Column(name = "note", nullable = false)
    private String note;

    @Column(name = "is_active", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "note_tag")
    private String noteTag;

    @Column(name = "is_checked", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isChecked;

    @Column(name = "extra_info")
    private String extraInfo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

}
```

User model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean isActive;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_info")
    private UserInfo userInfo;

}
```

NoteController:

```
...
@PostMapping("/addNote")
    public Note createNote(@RequestBody Note note) {
        return noteService.save(note);
    }
```

NoteService:

```
...
 public Note save(Note note) {
        return noteRepository.save(note);
    }
```

NoteRepository:

```
  Note save(Note note);
```

[Request and Response:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJeRw.jpg)

I want to post a note and make it belong to a user.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to separate you request/dto/response classes from the entity ones.

Anyway you are not saving the relationship between `Note` and `User` because your `Note` entity does not have a fk to the `User` entity, but a `User` field. In the request, you are passing a `user_id` field that is not mapped to anything, so it is not deserialized.

A possible solution is to have a `NoteRequest`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class NoteRequest {
    private String checklistName;
    private String note;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private String noteTag;
    private Boolean isChecked;
    private String extraInfo;
    private Long userId;
}
```

map it into a `Note`, manually or for example with an objectMapper

```
Note noteEntity = objectMapper.convertValue(noteRequest, Note.class)
```

retrieve the `User` (or its reference, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572207/how-to-save-foreign-key-entity-in-jpa)) and use it to save the `Note` entity

```
User userEntity = userRepository.findById(noteRequest.getUserId());
noteEntity.setUser(userEntity);
return noteRepository.save(note);
```